# Hiding label guidelines on Highcharts pie charts

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts, I've been using the dataLabel formatter to return an empty string value for zero values.  This effectively hides the label for zero values.  However, on pie charts, there is a guideline that points to each pie slice, even if the slice has a zero value. I can't seem to remove these guidelines without directly manipulating the DOM elements.  I'd like to keep the empty pie slices in the chart because I am dynamically updating the chart based on user-manipulated filter criteria, but I would like to hide the guidelines pointing to empty pie slices.

Does anyone know of a way to configure Highcharts remove the guidelines pointing to empty pie slices?  I am able clear out the label itself using the formatter below:

```
formatter: function ()
{
   var y = this.y;
   if (y == 0)
     return "";
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the formatter function is evaluating the value to display, the context has access to the guide-line path element.  I was able to hide the guideline by making the following change to the formatter:

```
formatter: function ()
{
  var y = this.y;
  //Hide the labels for empty pie slices
  if (y == 0)
  {
    //If there is a pie chart label guideline, hide it
     if (this.point.connector)
        $(this.point.connector.element).attr("stroke", "#FFFFFF");
    return "";
  }
  //If the label guideline was previously hidden, show it
  if (this.point.connector)
     $(this.point.connector.element).attr("stroke", "#000000");

  ...
 }
```

Comment: Well but why you cannot use return null ?

Comment: Returning null does not seem to cause the empty pie slice guideline to disappear, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

```
 if(this.y == 0)
                            return null    
                        else
                            return this.y
```

Answer (score 0):

Make connector width 0.

```
dataLabels: {
    connectorWidth: 0,
    ...
}
```